# How can I add "outer join conditions with ON clause" in JPA with Hibernate as persistence provider?

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jpa

This approach fails when using hibernate:

```
SELECT e, COUNT(p) FROM Employee e JOIN e.projects p ON e.timeEmployed <=  p.timeStarted GROUP BY e
```

The following test:

```
package provider.hibernate;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import context.ContextConfig;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ContextConfig.class })
@Transactional
// @ActiveProfiles("eclipseLink")
@ActiveProfiles("hibernate")
public class JoinFilterTest {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    public void testJoinFilter() {
        entityManager.createQuery(
                "SELECT e, COUNT(p) FROM Employee e JOIN e.projects p"
                        + " ON e.timeEmployed <= p.timeStarted GROUP BY e")
                .getResultList();
    }

}
```

fails with an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements [Select e, COUNT(p) FROM entity.Employee e JOIN e.projects p ON e.timeEmployed <= p.timeStarted GROUP BY e]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:289)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at provider.hibernate.JoinFilterTest.testJoinFilter(JoinFilterTest.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:81)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:216)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:82)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:67)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) 
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) 
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements [Select e, COUNT(p) FROM entity.Employee e JOIN e.projects p ON e.timeEmployed <= p.timeStarted GROUP BY e]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
        ... 36 more
```

The employee entity class is as follows:

```
package entity;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;

@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "employees")
    private Collection<Project> projects;

    @Basic
    private Instant timeEmployed;

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        timeEmployed = Instant.now();
    }

}
```

The project entity class is as follows:

```
package entity;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

@Entity
public class Project {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Employee> employees;

    @Basic
    private Instant timeStarted;

}
```

The jpql query in the test works perfectly in eclipse link.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot group a whole entity with some aggregation functions.

You could do this instead:

```
SELECT 
    e.id, 
    COUNT(p) 
FROM Employee e 
JOIN e.projects p 
WHERE e.timeEmployed <= p.timeStarted 
GROUP BY e.id
```

Using the returned ids, you can fetch the entities with a single secondary query:

```
select e FROM Employee e where id in :ids
```

Comment: The idea of using a secondary query doesn't quite appeal to me, but as you rightly suggested, it seems I have little choice as I don't intend to switch to EclipseLink. Hopefully Hibernate will support this soon and we can take advantage of OUTER JOIN conditions rather than issue secondary queries.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I settled on is quite similar to your suggestion but somewhat reversed. The reason for moving the query condition to the ON clause rather than specifying it on the WHERE clause is to ensure that all Employee entities are included in the result.

As a first step I selected the employees with

```
SELECT e FROM Employee e
```

Then I issued a secondary query to count projects started after each employee was employed:

```
SELECT 
    e.id, 
    COUNT(p) 
FROM Employee e 
JOIN e.projects p 
WHERE e.timeEmployed <= p.timeStarted AND e in :employees 
GROUP BY e
```

The list of employees from the first query is passed as a parameter (:employees) to the second query.

The employee id (e.id) was selected in the second query to make it possible to map the project count to the appropriate employee. This is obviously more work but I have to live with that for now.